# Howto proxy a UIView with different name between frameworks?

Tags: swift, objective-c

I want to do like this

FrameworkA

```
import UIKit
import FrameworkB

class Some:UIView{

}
```

FrameworkB

```
class SecondSome:Some{

}
```

The key is FrameworkB must not import FrameworkA. This is because IOC Principle

How can I pass "Some" in to frameworkB with anyway?.

Comment: You can't subclass an unkown class. What are you trying to accomplish? Why the Objective-C tag?

Comment: Here I want to register Class on Runtime. and resolve from other module. but i think its not possible.maybe defining/injecting a typealias from frameworkA into frameworkb..

Comment: Why do you want to subclass an unknown class? Can't you use a protocol, extension or generics?